# How to refactor this SQLite query to prevent SQL Injection

Tags: android, sqlite, prepared-statement, sql-injection

Into a ContentProvider of an Android app (java) I have this SQLiteDatabase query:

```
db.execsql("SELECT " +
    FormsColumns._ID + ", " +
    FormsColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + ", " +
    FormsColumns.DISPLAY_SUBTEXT + ", " +
    FormsColumns.DESCRIPTION + ", " +
    FormsColumns.JR_FORM_ID + ", " +
    FormsColumns.MD5_HASH + ", " +
    FormsColumns.DATE + ", " +
    FormsColumns.FORM_MEDIA_PATH + ", " +
    FormsColumns.FORM_FILE_PATH + ", " +
    FormsColumns.LANGUAGE   + ", " +
    FormsColumns.SUBMISSION_URI + ", " +
    "CASE WHEN " + MODEL_VERSION + " IS NOT NULL THEN " +
    "CAST(" + MODEL_VERSION + " AS TEXT) ELSE NULL END, " +
    ((oldVersion != 3) ? "" : (FormsColumns.BASE64_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY + ", ")) + FormsColumns.JRCACHE_FILE_PATH + " " + 
    "FROM " + FORMS_TABLE_NAME);
```

It is not a simple query, I know how to refactor a simple query with SQLiteDatabase.query() method to prevent SQL injection, but in this case i don't know how to resolve this problem.
If I will use the SQLiteStatements class with "?" in place of the variables to be changed, could it work?
How do you all suggest me to solve?
Thanks.

Comment: Use prepared statements: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html

Comment: there might be no need to prevent injection, because no user-input is involved. can you create a test-scenario, in which you would inject into some local database?

Comment: Thanks, I resolved this problem.